# Count the number of Enum values in list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have an enum like this :

```
public enum PlayResultEnum
{
    First, Cooperate, Defect
}
```

I create a list of this:

```
    public List<PlayResultEnum> Agent1Result=new List<PlayResultEnum>();
    public List<PlayResultEnum> Agent2Result=new List<PlayResultEnum>();
```

I need to count ,for example **First** values in my list using lambda (Linq) .

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var count = Agent1Result.Count(c => c == PlayResultEnum.First);
```

Or another way:

```
var count = Agent1Result.Count(c => (int)c == 0);
```

It will work if your `PlayResultEnum.First` is the first value and you didn't set another value manually.From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

> By default, the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is increased by 1.

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking...

If you want to know the number of items in the list, you don't need linq, just do:

```
var count = Agent1Result.Count;
```

If you want to know the number of items in the list of a specific type, do:

```
var count = Agent1Resut.Count(x => x == PlaEnumResult.First);
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting all the occurrences, you would do something like this:

```
Dictionary<PlayResultEnum, int> countResults 
           = Agent1Result.GroupBy(x => x)
                         .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value.Count);
```

Now you can get the occurrences for every enum value:

```
Console.WriteLine(countResults[PlayResultEnum.First]);
```